# Maui WebView AudioContext working on some devices not on others

Tags: android, audio, webview, maui

I have an Android app/game built from HTML/Javascript/WebGL and packaged with Maui.  The original game loads sound efect .mp3's from http via XMLHttpRequest.  That didn't work with file url of packaged mp3's in Maui so I shipped my first version of the game without sfx.

Coming back to it I found that I could Base64 encode the mp3's and embed them as data url's and that seemed to work.  It works with all the emulators I have downloaded, and with my older Samsung and a Pixel, but I have one friend with a newer Samsung and there is no sound for him.

As a test, instead of playing an mp3 I create an oscillator node and play it. The newer Samsung A32 plays nothing. When I put up js alerts there is a click sound on the OK button.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.